# LinkedIn post Reactions API shows Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiReactions.FINDER-entity.20231001

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get all the reactions to my organization's posts via APIs. I focused on one post first
Some notes:

- Other APIs are working fine (i.e. posts, share statistics)
- I have permission to r_organization_social per the notes here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/reactions-api?view=li-lms-2024-01&tabs=http
- I also have permission to r_organization_social_feed
- I followed the instructions on LinkedIn API doc and configured this URL
  https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(entity:urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A##############)?q=entity
- I added these headers [Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EyGX.png)
- I am the admin of the organization's page

And I keep getting "Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiReactions.FINDER-entity.20231001"

Could you provide some assistance or alternative please?

I tried:

- adding the encoded actor to the URL
- adding the sort parameter

I was expecting to the the likes and other reactions from the post.

The likes I can get directly from the share statistics, but not the other reactions.

I can see the message about deprecation of APIs, but I don't see any other option to get the Reactions.